# Use .css on var text

Tags: javascript, css

I want to style a `var text`, how to do?

`var text='<br>Hello<br><br><ul>';`

I was thinking this but didnt work: `var text='<br>Hello<br><br><ul>.css("color:red","border:3px solid black")';`

Comment: this is too broad sorry.This question shows that you have not even tried to find your answer by researchning.....https://stackoverflow.com/help. Javascript variables can not have any styles, you only can style `HTML Elements`.

Comment: Check out the excellent [W3 school on CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text in a span and add the style to that.

```
var text = '<br><span style="color:red; border: 3px solid black;">Hello</span><br><br><ul>';
```

Comment: i don't think that this question deserves an answer...

Comment: @Barmar - thank you, Mister Barmar.